# HTML/MYSql - Add Textfield to Database but before look if it exists

Tags: php, html, mysql

I would like to know how it is possible to do the following:

You can write something in the Textfield, like: "example1" (it gets sent to the mysql database)
Then you click Submit and after that,
Noone can ever Sumbit and(send the text to the mysql database) with the same textfield

So i would like to know how i can create a database which gets the info and a HTML function which checks if the Text already exists inside of the Database

Im a noob :c
Thank you

Comment: try with ajax with onkeyup event of text filed

Comment: This question is too general, we can help you fix code but just asking a generic question is too big for this board.